# Спарсить базу MySql Laravel

Tags: laravel, dle

Есть 2 сайта один на CMS DLE, а второй на Laravel. И есть задача перенести все данные из базы сайта на DLE в Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Была похожая задача, но только с другой системой управления. Как вариант можно сделать так.

В вашем проекте в `config/database.php` описываете еще одно подключение к базе данных сайта dle. Создаете новые временные модели связанные с необходимыми таблицы базы данных dle, если необходимо связи также описываете.

Дальше пробегаетесь по моделям базы данных dle и заполняете модели вашего проекта laravel.

Comment: Спасибо все сработало.